# How to make sure only one BooleanField is true for a single model?

Tags: django

I have a django project in which I have a Videos model. On my index template page I only want to show a single video, the one that has isFeatured equal to true. Whenever I change another video's isFeatured property to true, it should make that property false for the former video.

I've checked out other stackoverflow questions about this but all of them are dealing with a foreign key, while my model is simpler and I think there is an easier solution for this.

This is how my model looks like:

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

Comment: Perhaps using an extra model with one element: a `ForeignKey` to the `Video` that is featured is a better modeling here, since then, by *design*, it is impossible to have multiple featured videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I managed to solve the problem by overriding the save method:

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isFeatured == True:
            Video.objects.filter(isFeatured=True).update(isFeatured=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

I'll wait a bit until I approve this answer, since I'm not very familiar with django so I don't know what problems this may or may not cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want or can't create another model then the only solution for you would be handling this by codes.

The only way you can get around this is that you have to change the rows with a code.

And to get it right, create a function that does this and use it everywhere instead of rewriting the code to avoid mistakes.

```
video_isfeatured_changer(video_id):
    # Change isFeatured for other featured videos to False.
    featured_videos = Video.objects.filter(isFeatured=True).update(isFeatured=False)

    video = Video.objects.get(pk=video_id)
    video.isFeatured = True
    video.save()
```

You can also override the `save()` method for `Video` model.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def mark_featured(self):
        self.objects.all().update(isFeatured=False)
        self.isFeatured = True
        return self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

Use as

```
video = Video.objects.get(...)
video.mark_featured()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first video with `isFeatured = True`

```
class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.url

    def homeheader(self):
       return self.filter(isFeatured=True).first()
```

You can use at the template like:

```
{{ videos.homeheader }}
```